# Random weight initialisation influence on a simple neural network

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

I am following a [book](https://github.com/iamtrask/Grokking-Deep-Learning) which has the following code:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)

streetlights = np.array([[1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1]])

walk_vs_stop = np.array([[1, 1, 0, 0]]).T


def relu(x):
    return (x > 0) * x


def relu2deriv(output):
    return output > 0


alpha = 0.2
hidden_layer_size = 4

# random weights from the first layer to the second
weights_0_1 = 2*np.random.random((3, hidden_layer_size)) -1
# random weights from the second layer to the output
weights_1_2 = 2*np.random.random((hidden_layer_size, 1)) -1


for iteration in range(60):
    layer_2_error = 0
    for i in range(len(streetlights)):
        layer_0 = streetlights[i : i + 1]
        layer_1 = relu(np.dot(layer_0, weights_0_1))
        layer_2 = relu(np.dot(layer_1, weights_1_2))

        layer_2_error += np.sum((layer_2 - walk_vs_stop[i : i + 1])) ** 2

        layer_2_delta = layer_2 - walk_vs_stop[i : i + 1]
        layer_1_delta = layer_2_delta.dot(weights_1_2.T) * relu2deriv(layer_1)

        weights_1_2 -= alpha * layer_1.T.dot(layer_2_delta)
        weights_0_1 -= alpha * layer_0.T.dot(layer_1_delta)

    if iteration % 10 == 9:
        print(f"Error: {layer_2_error}")
```

Which outputs:

```
# Error: 0.6342311598444467
# Error: 0.35838407676317513
# Error: 0.0830183113303298
# Error: 0.006467054957103705
# Error: 0.0003292669000750734
# Error: 1.5055622665134859e-05
```

I understand everything but this part is not explained and I am not sure why it is the way it is:

```
weights_0_1 = 2*np.random.random((3, hidden_layer_size)) -1
weights_1_2 = 2*np.random.random((hidden_layer_size, 1)) -1
```

I don't understand:

1. Why there is `2*` the whole matrix and why is there a `-1`
2. If I change `2` to `3` my error becomes greatly lower `# Error: 5.616513576418916e-13`
3. I tried changing the `2` to many other numbers along with the change of `-1` to many other numbers I get `# Error: 2.0` most of the time or the `Error` is much worst than combination of `3` and `-1`.

I can't seem to grasp the relationship and the purpose of multiplying the random weights by a number and subracting a number afterwards.

P.S. The idea of the network is to understand a streetlight pattern when people should go and when they should stop depending what combination of the lights in `streetlight` is on / off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot of ways to initialize neural network, and it's a current research subject as it can have a great impact on performance and training time. Some rules of thumb :

- avoid having only one value for all weights, as they would all update the same
- avoid having too large weights that could make your gradient too high
- avoid having too small weights that could make your gradient vanish

In your case, the goal is just to have something between [-1;1] :

1. np.random.random gives you a float in [0;1]
2. multiply by 2 gives you something in [0;2]
3. substract 1 gives you a number in [-1;1]

Comment: I think it just works better in your particular case, it's just noise.

Answer (score 0):

`2*np.random.random((3, 4)) -1` is a way to generated `3*4=12` random number from uniform distribution of half-open interval `[-1, +1)` i.e including `-1` but excluding `+1`.

This is equivalent to more readable code

```
np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (3, 4))
```